# Xamarin Cross Platform IOS App Getting Error i.e The App is terminated

Tags: ios, xamarin

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dJUOa.png) I am developing a cross platform app in xamarin. My project is properly running in android simulator but while running on mac IOS Simulator but I am getting an error i.e The app is terminated on run time.
My MacOs Version is `10.13.3 High Sierra`

Visual Studio for `Mac Version is 7.3.3 Community 2017`
In Windows, `Visual Studio Enterprise 2015`
`XCode is of 9.2`.

Comment: How could we know if we don't have further information? Any code or detailed error?

Comment: Try creating a dummy project in Xcode directly and run it. Could be that Xcode needs to run some install scripts.